# How can I read the stripe size of a bcache device?

Tags: c, linux

I would like to get the stripe size of a bcache block device in a Linux system in C.

In the shell I can get this e.g. via `cat /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stripe_size`.

How can I achieve this/ what is the "standard" way of doing it in C?

I have read through https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/md/bcache, but unfortunately did not find a way to access the information.

Is parsing `sysfs` really the only way to get this?

This would really get ugly, because the content is e.g. `1.0M` instead of e.g. `1048576`.

Comment: Why would you expect parsing sysfs to not be the _desired_ way? It's a clean general-purpose interface via the Bad Old Days where everything had to have a dedicated ioctl and data structure and everything had to be compiled against the _exact_ right kernel version's headers.

Comment: ...now, yes, there are more direct mechanisms if what you're writing _is a kernel module_; but in every other case there's a boundary between kernelspace and userspace that needs to be crossed regardless, and sysfs is a very well-designed way to cross it. (Similarly, look at modern versions of `ps`, `htop`, etc -- on Linux they're using procfs, not ioctls anymore; that's for good cause).

Comment: (er, that should have been "vs" rather than "via" the Bad Old Days)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Mainly because then I am independent on whatever the block device is called/ where it is copied to/ manually created or whatever.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Beyond that, it is really bad to parse. Example: `1.0M` instead of e.g. `1048576`. For me it looks like the interface is more designed to be consumed by humans, than by machines.

Comment: Huh? You still need to get a handle on the device, even if you're using ioctls; I don't know how you'd expect to not need to know a name.

Comment: If you don't want to write the code yourself, consider using libbcachefs -- that way you're going through the same codepaths used by the official bcachefs-tools project.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For the device file, however the user called it, for sure I have the name. I hoped that I do not need to go through to calculate the name of the directory in sysfs.
But the really bad part is the parsing of the file content.
I have implemented that, but hoped that there is a less complicated way.